# Cancel route and redirect to other route without displaying the original content in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I want to check an http services to see if a user is authenticated and if it has permission to see the certain page (controller) in AngularJS 1.2.0rc1.

I have this scenario: 
User A wants to visit http://www.example.com/content. Now this content should not be accessible when he or she is not authenticated. If the user is not authenticated, they should be redirected to http://www.example.com/login.

Now I managed to do this, but I see the rendered html of the content page briefly. I don't want this. How do I redirect to the login page, without rendering the content page?

I register my routes as such:

```
$routeProvider.when('/login', route.resolve('Login', false))
$routeProvider.when('/content', route.resolve('Content', true))
```

Now I've tried this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, route) {
    if (route.requiresLogin) {
        $http.get('/api/user/loggedin/').then(function (response) {
            if (response !== 'true') {
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Which works, but I still see the content of the html of the other page (content) flashing.

I've read that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962351/angularjs-detecting-stalling-and-cancelling-route-changes) that you can also try to change the resolve functionality when the route is resolved:

```
    var resolve = function (baseName, requiresLogin) {
    var routeDef = {};
    var dependencies = [routeConfig.getControllersDirectory() + baseName + 'Controller.js'];

    routeDef.templateUrl = routeConfig.getViewsDirectory() + baseName.toLowerCase() + '.html';
    routeDef.controller = baseName + 'Controller';
    routeDef.requiresLogin = requiresLogin;
    routeDef.resolve = {
        load: ['$q', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location', function ($q, $rootScope, $http, $location) {
            console.log(requiresLogin);
            if (requiresLogin) {
                return checkLoggedIn($q, $rootScope, $http, $location);
            } else {
                return resolveDependencies($q, $rootScope, dependencies);
            }
        }]
    };

    return routeDef;
}
```

But here the page is also displayed briefly.

Hope that you can help me out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first answer should work, but to do it using [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) I would use `defer.resolve()` or `defer.reject("rejection_reason")` then I would listen for a `$routeChangeError` in a top-level controller that is bound to an an element outside of the ng-view that the routeProvider manages.

So in your HTML, something like:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="DocumentCtrl">
  <div ng-view>
  </div>
</body>
```

Then that route of yours would be defined something like:

```
when('/home', {
  templateUrl: templateUrl blah,
  controller: baseName + 'Controller',
  resolve: {
    load: function($q, MY_USER_SERVICE){
      var defer = $q.defer();
      if(~MY USER LOGGED_IN LOGIC RETURNS TRUE~){
        defer.resolve();
      } else {
        defer.reject("not_logged_in");
      }
      return defer.promise;

    }
  }
}).
```

Then my DocumentCtrl controller would contain:

```
$scope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(evt,current,previous,rejection){
  if(rejection == "not_logged_in"){
    //DO SOMETHING
  } else {
    //OR DO SOMETHING ELSE
  }
});
```

I'm running the above and there's no flash of any views that shouldn't be loaded.

Comment: Confirmed as the way to deal with this, while not showing the original routed page. Promises are not necessary, a simple throw new Error ('') is sufficient. Key is that only an error will stop the current navigation. Maybey a future version of Angular will bring us a decent way to handle conditional (injected) redirection.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Se we can simply return true in the load function, or conditionally throw an error above that if we don't want to allow access? In every example I have seen a promises have been used.

Comment: Using UI-router has made all these easy. Simply writing `$state.go('state')` inside `resolve` redirects you before loading the controller.